# Sniper 3D assassin Ahnselmman air tour

Tags: sniper-3d-assassin

I am stuck in Ahnselmman city in primary jobs 4/40 air tour. It seems no bullet is going toward the target. I have tested two types of sniper rifles and also pistol but no chance. Is this a bug or this level needs a special trick?

Edit: I use android 9 on Galaxy note 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally passed this mission using a shotgun which not needs a precise targeting (I am using a tier 19 shotgun but I guess any shotgun will do that).

If you are stuck in this stage and you have no shotgun, you just need to collect coins by accomplishing "Wanted" missions and buy suitable sniper rifles for main missions.